# How to save the VS 2010 settings in Project file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012

Is there is a way to save the vs setting in project file(csproj/csproj.user).For eg i have two project called x and y,  x should loads with a settings(font,fontsize,tab space) and different from y and then i don't want to import and export the *.vssettings in my vs every time.

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: Usually changing the Property or Option is just fine.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't directly possible, as the preferences are not project (or solution) based.

There are extensions that might provide a solution for you, like [EditorConfig](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c8bccfe2-650c-4b42-bc5c-845e21f96328)

If you're looking to simply share your settings between VS installs on multiple systems, there is a cloud sync feature in VS2012 (or you can use third party tools like [this](http://blogs.telerik.com/justteam/posts/12-10-22/save-your-visual-studio-settings-in-the-cloud.aspx))